# Расставьте знакие препинания правильно

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, причастный-оборот

Охваченный страстью к жизни он в бешеном темпе двигался вперёд не останавливаясь нигде.

Answer (score 2):

О**хваченный страстью к жизни,** он в бешеном темпе двигался вперёд, **не останавливаясь нигде.**

1) Причастный оборот, отнесенный к местоимению, обособляется в любой позиции.

2) Деепричастный оборот также обособляется.

Может не обособляться одиночное деепричастие в значении наречия: Он  двигался вперёд **не останавливаясь**. Или: Он  двигался вперёд **в бешеном темпе, не останавливаясь** (однородные обстоятельства).

Answer (score 0):

1. [**Причастный оборот**](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-00000000320b2387f51b662265394613) (***охваченный страстью к жизни***) обособляется независимо от его места в предложении, если относится к личному местоимению (***он***).
2. [**Деепричастный оборот**](http://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/deeprichastnyy-oborot-pravilo-i-primery) (***не останавливаясь нигде***) в предложениях выделяется запятыми с двух сторон независимо от того, в какой позиции относительно глагола-сказуемого (***двигался***) он находится.

Правильная пунктуация такая:
**Охваченный страстью к жизни, он в бешеном темпе двигался вперёд, не останавливаясь нигде.**

*Могла ли вообразить, что, **впервые охваченная безумной страстью,** она поставит на карту все: свою честь, положение в обществе, будущее и даже жизнь...*
Л. Клейпас. Нам не жить друг без друга

*Мы шли по двенадцать и тринадцать часов в день, **нигде не останавливаясь.***
Е. Ковалевский

*И Базаров и Аркадий ответили ей безмолвным поклоном, сели в экипаж и, **уже нигде не останавливаясь,** отправились домой, в Марьино...*
И. С. Тургенев. Отцы и дети